# What is the best way to implement a serial buffer using vector<char>?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to read data from a serial device and put it into a buffer to be consumed by another thread. Basically, I want to achieve this:

```
while(!exit){
    // read from fd and push into the vector<char> buffer
}
```

And do it the right way in C++. I know how to get this done in C, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

From what I've found so far, people have been suggesting:

```
read(fd, &vector[0], vector.size());
```

But, I'm not convinced. Especially since modifying the `&vector[0]` directly doesn't update `size()` (or does it?) and seems like an indirect way to modify the underlying array. I'd like to avoid using `open()` and `read()` as well, if I could help, as they aren't really C++. Some form of istream would be awesome here!

Also, I couldn't find any examples of how to neatly "pop" the data from this vector when the data needs to be consumed from the other thread. I believe, and I'm certainly not 100% sure about this, that if there's only one writer thread and one reader thread for this vector, I wouldn't need any special code for thread safety. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If it matters at all, the data in the vector is binary.

Comment: Indeed, `&vector[0]` directly doesn't update `size()`. So, you always have to resize vector before filling it in with data. For example, the following is better:

`vector.resize( n_bytes );
read(fd, &vector[0], vector.size());`

Comment: Do you really have to use dynamic size? Because when you hit the moment when vector reallocates, you'll have a huge timing jitter. Isn't predictable real time response important in this case?

Comment: I would recommend using a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of some kind. [Boost has an implementation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) Not quite what you're asking for, though...

Comment: This question is also not clear about the synchronization of the reader and writer.

Comment: `if there's only one writer thread and one reader thread for this vector, I wouldn't need any special code for thread safety.` Yes, you definately would. When the producer sticks data into your buffer, things like indexes into the buffer, the count of data, whatever, needs to be updated. While that's being updated, the consumer could observe some inconsistent state and trash your buffer (or worse).

Comment: @user3528438: Performance is not really a constraint here.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for pointing out the need for synchronization! I thought the STL containers provided some sort of basic thread safety. I can handle the sync issues. I just wanted to find out if there is a nice and clean way to use the vector for a buffer. I can fill in everything else to make it work.

Comment: @Kulki There is a decent section on thread safety of the container classes [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, I've always used a fixed size array of `uint8_t` for serial communications.  This provides a faster access than going through a `vector`; and most serial I/O has been time sensitive.

A fixed size means no time spent resizing.

Comment: I've always done that too but I've some extra time on my hands right now, which I'm spending on trying to improve my C++ skills :). I'll wait another day or so and if I don't get a better answer, I'll gladly accept yours!